# Django dump data for a single model?

Tags: django, django-models, loaddata, dumpdata

Can I perform a `dumpdata` in [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_(web_framework)) on just a single model, rather than the whole app, and if so, how?

For an app it would be:

```
python manage.py dumpdata myapp
```

However, I want some specific model, such as "myapp.mymodel" to be dumped. The reason being, I have some huge, 3 million records plus, datasets in the same app that I would not like dumped.

Comment: I find your question not easy to understand. You want to load an SQL dump into your database? Or you want to do some sort of toString() on and instance of a model?

Answer (score 301, accepted):

As of version 1.1 and greater, the Django [`dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata) management command allows you to dump data from individual tables:

```
./manage.py dumpdata myapp1 myapp2.my_model
```

You can also separate multiple apps and models on the command line. Here's the canonical definition:

```
django-admin dumpdata [app_label[.ModelName] [app_label[.ModelName] ...]]
```

Comment: gath, didn't understood the negative vote on post which is almost 2 years old. Moreover above code worked fine even with v1.1 . New features in new releases doesn't make older answers invalid.

Comment: And how do I add this data at another instance of the app?.

Comment: To make human readable json use flag `--indent 4` after `dumpdata`

Answer (score 118):

As noted, you can't do this through a manage.py command in Django 1.0.  However you could use a script to export the JSON file, and load it using `loaddata`:

```
from django.core import serializers
from myproject.myapp import models
data = serializers.serialize("json", models.MyModel.objects.all())
out = open("mymodel.json", "w")
out.write(data)
out.close()
```

Comment: This is a great script because you can get even more granular if you'd like.  If you instead do a .filter(...) on line three above you can dump just the specific records you want.

Comment: Is there a way to dump many-to-many field values for several objects with this?

Comment: I think I'll try https://github.com/davedash/django-fixture-magic

Answer (score 22):

A specific model to a specific file:

```
python manage.py dumpdata app_label.ModelName > specific_file.json
```

and to load it to another app: first move or copy the file to the app where you want process it, then:

```
python manage.py loaddata specific_file.json
```

Answer (score 12):

Take all data into json format from django model.

**Syntax:**

```
python manage.py dumpdata app_name.model_name
```

For **example** dumping data from group_permission model which reside in default auth app in django.

```
python manage.py dumpdata auth.group_permission
```

For output take a look on **console**.

Answer (score 6):

I think you had the solution in your question. You can dump an individual model like this:

```
./manage.py dumpdata myapp.my_model
```

Comment: i tried it before posting. had no luck. i'm in django 1.0. also tried myapp.models.mymodel?

Answer (score 5):

For success I had to say it twice, and specify the model two times, like:

```
./manage.py dumpdata myapp2.my_model myapp2.my_model
```

If I only said

```
./manage.py dumpdata myapp2 myapp2.my_model
```

I got flooded with all the models in myapp2, despite the fact that I specified my_model.

Answer (score 3):

For newbies in Django and Python like me, this might be useful:

if you want to only dump a single row (of, obviously, a single table) and you have for example the app "merchant" and the model is also named "Merchant", and you usually import it using a fully qualified name like this: `merchant.models.Merchant`; **do not even try to use this name**. The syntax is as follows:

```
# only dumps the merchant with id = 123, pretty printed
python manage.py dumpdata merchant.Merchant --pks 123 --indent 2
```

Answer (score 2):

To write it on specific file:

```
python manage.py dumpdata app_label.ModelName app_label.ModelName2 > fixtures/specic.json
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dump only the specified objects of a model, you can use the [--pks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-dumpdata-pks) optional argument for the dumpdata command.

> --pks PRIMARY_KEYS Outputs only the objects specified by a comma separated list of primary keys. This is only available when dumping
> one model. By default, all the records of the model are output.

Answer (score 2):

I think the accepted answer is old and needs a refresher in 2023 with the detailed approach.

I had the similar problem where I had to create fixtures for specific models from different apps having specific id's. Moreover I had to create just one fixture for all models. so that we don't have to load individual fixtures rather just one fixture for all models.

I did all of this by creating a custom command that calls the `dumpdata` internally for each specific model with the specific ids like the following:

***products/models.py***

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2)
```

***reviews/models.py***

```
class Review(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)        
    text = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def natural_key(self):
       return self.title, self.timestamp


class Response(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And following is the command that creates one fixtures for specific  models from different apps with specific id's:

***generate_fixture.py***

```
from django.core.management import BaseCommand, call_command
from io import StringIO
import json

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('id', type=int, help='Primary Key Of Product')

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        id = options.get('id')

        if product := Product.objects.filter(id=id).first():
            product_fixture = self.get_fixture('products.Product', str(id))

            review_ids = list(
                Review.objects.filter(product__id=id).values_list('id',flat=True)
            )
            review_ids = ','.join([str(review_id) for review_id in review_ids])
            review_fixture = self.get_fixture('reviews.Review', review_ids)

            output = [json.loads(product_fixture)]
            output.extend(json.loads(review_fixture))
            with open('model_fixtures.json', "w") as file:
                json.dump(output, file)
        else:
            print(f"Product with id {id} does not exists!")

    def get_fixture(self, label, pks):
        args = ['dumpdata', '--natural-foreign', '--natural-primary', label]
        with StringIO() as buffer:
            call_command(*args, pks=pks, stdout=buffer)
            data = buffer.getvalue()
        return data
```

Now you can run the command with the id like this:

`python manage.py generate_fixture 50`

And fixture of the models will be generated in just one fixture file which can be loaded like this:

`python manage.py loaddata model_fixtures.json`

Comment: This was useful, thank you! The code I modified from this basically worked except the first parameter to `get_fixture` needs to be 'self' and we need to be careful about the format that's output so that it works with the loaddata command https://stackoverflow.com/a/54617472/1552045

Comment: Thanks @MikeS for pointing out the typo. If you think anything else needs to be changed feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could make another app and copy the model but point it to the existing table with the db_table meta option. Then you could just dump the models you copied into the new app. You existing app wouldn't be affected.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a management command the generate a fixture on a per model basis.
Fixtures can be generated by running:

```
./manage generate_fixtures app.model.MyModel --file=dump/MyModel.json
```

code at: https://gist.github.com/2394883

Answer (score 0):

For DUMPING data out of the specific model for specific APP.

---

If we take EXAMPLE where we have in a MAIN PROJECT (We go call it ***project***) and in this MAIN PROJECT we have two (02) others applications (We go call each app like this ***APP1*** and ***APP2***) we can do like that

---

1. **python manage.py dumpdata APP1.name_of_model >APP1/fixtures/name_of_model .json**
2. **python manage.py dumpdata APP2.name_of_model  >APP2/fixtures/name_of_model .json**