# Decoding unicode escape avoiding quotes and some other symbols needed to escape

Tags: python, json, unicode, dumpdata

I've got a problem with encoding unicode escapes. After `python manage.py dumpdata`, I have `json` with escaped strings.

I need to get readable strings, so I tried to use

```
json_data.decode("unicode_escape").encode("utf8")
```

but `decode("unicode_escape")` also decodes symbols like `\n`, `\"` etc. And ofcourse I get not valid json.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could try `manage.py dumpdata --format=xml > output.xml`, which handles unicode correctly. That and other things to try found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137501/django-dumpdata-utf-8-unicode

Comment: Oh, ofcourse, with xml everything is ok. But is any way do solve this problem with JSON?

Comment: Can't say I've tried. I suppose you could update the dumpdata code. You'll probably need to do something along these lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865180/unicode-values-in-strings-are-escaped-when-dumping-to-json-in-python

Comment: Thanks!  `json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)` works for me.