# Django dumpdata fails on special characters

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to dump my entire DB to a json. When I run `python manage.py dumpdata > data.json` I get an error:

```
(env) PS C:\dev\watch_something> python manage.py dumpdata > data.json
CommandError: Unable to serialize database: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0130' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>
Exception ignored in: <generator object cursor_iter at 0x0460C140>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\watch_something\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1602, in cursor_iter
    cursor.close()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.
```

It's because one of the characters in my DB is a sepcial character. How can I dump the DB correctly?

FYI, all other DB functionalities work fine

Answer (score 84, accepted):

One solution is to use `./manage.py dumpdata -o data.json` instead of `./manage.py dumpdata > data.json`.

Another solution is to use [Python's UTF-8 mode](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=utf%20mode#id5), run:

```
python -Xutf8 ./manage.py dumpdata > data.json
```

Comment: It really works, thanks a lot

Comment: works for me as well. Nice solution.

Comment: On Windows, using `python -Xutf8 manage.py dumpdata -o data.json` worked. Was failing without the `-Xutf8` option otherwise.

Comment: Yep! This worked  Thanks!

Comment: The only clear solution

Comment: what does -o do?

Comment: how can i add it back to the database?

Comment: Using `manage.py loaddata` (followed by the name of your file) (place your file in a `fixtures/` directory in your app)

Comment: python -Xutf8 manage.py dumpdata -o data.json worked for me

Comment: I was getting this error on Ubuntu.  I was already using the -o option to specify the output file name.  The problematic field contained OCR'ed data that would many times have random characters.  Every so often during the dump it would say: "Unable to serialize database: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 3: ordinal not in range(256)."  If I deleted the offending characters in one record, it would soon encounter another record and issue the same error message. Using the -Xutf8 option caused the json to be output with no errors.

Answer (score 9):

To save `json` data in django the [TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) is used:

> The default encoding is now `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` (...)

In documentation of `locale.getpreferredencoding` fuction we can [read](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding):

> Return the encoding used for text data, according to user preferences. User preferences are expressed differently on different systems, and might not be available programmatically on some systems, so this function only returns a guess.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34345136/645146) I found "hacky" but working method to overwrite these settings:

In file `settings.py` of your django project add these lines:

```
import _locale
_locale._getdefaultlocale = (lambda *args: ['en_US', 'utf8'])
```

Comment: If anyone should stumble upon this, please note that the syntax "python manage.py dumpdata > giveme.json" might still fail with this solution, but in my case "python manage.py dumpdata -o pleasegiveme.json" with the hacky solution above did work.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution from djangoproject.com
You go to Settings there's a "Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support", box in "Language" - "Administrative Language Settings" - "Change system locale" - "Region Settings".
If we apply that, and reboot, then we get a sensible, modern, default encoding from Python.
[djangoproject.com](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32439)

the settings box looks like this. Enable the check and restart your system
[image: Windows settings]

Comment: This is now documented in the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/windows/#common-pitfalls) as well.

Answer (score 1):

On windows the way i solved mine was
Add to your settings

```
import _locale
_locale._getdefaultlocale = (lambda *args: ['en_US', 'utf8'])
```

run this on shell only on windows

```
python -Xutf8 manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes > db.json
```

I actually did this it worked

```
python -Xutf8 manage.py dumpdata -o data.json
```

But wasnt showing data from my installed apps

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple Python environments, before applying workarounds, it's worth checking that you issue `python manage.py` against the correct environment. That was my case where I met the same error: the database was created under containerized environment on Linux, with a higher Python version, but Django and other packages were present also in the legacy local environment on Windows. As well, the project directory was attached to the container as a volume, and the content was identical locally and in the container. So, I just mix up and ran `manage.py` locally instead of being attached to the container.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the current best way: In the directory `Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers`, you open the `json.py` file. In the `json.py file`, find the section:

```
class Serializer(PythonSerializer):  
           .................  
           def _init_options(self):  
                  .............  
                  # Default is False  
                  self.json_kwargs.setdefault("ensure_ascii", False)  
                  # You fix False to True  
                  self.json_kwargs.setdefault("ensure_ascii", True)
```