# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 460: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, django, postgresql, utf-8, pgadmin

I've got a problem with the command `loaddata` of my Django app.

When I run this command, this `UnicodeDecodeError` appears because of the "é" that are in my database table.

i've try with many type of database on pgAdmin with different encode type like "UTF-8", "latin-1" or "win1252" or different "character type" or "collation" settings like "C" or "french_switzerland.1252"  but every time there is this error.

Here is more information about my work space.

Let me know if you need more informations, I don't give you too much, I don't want to give useless information.

I know there are other questions which look similar to mine but I don't understand the answers. There are explanations about why there is the error but not about how to solve it.

- I am on Windows 10
- I'm using Pycharm 2020.3.2
- Pgadmin v4

the complete error :

```
(venv) C:\Users\Mathias\PycharmProjects\yufindProject>python manage.py loaddata ask/dumps/ask.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()

  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

  File "C:\Users\Mathias\PycharmProjects\yufindProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

  File "C:\Users\Mathias\PycharmProjects\yufindProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execut
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

  File "C:\Users\Mathias\PycharmProjects\yufindProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)

  File "C:\Users\Mathias\PycharmProjects\yufindProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)

  File "C:\Users\Mathias\PycharmProjects\yufindProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 72, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)

  File "C:\Users\Mathias\PycharmProjects\yufindProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 114, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)

  File "C:\Users\Mathias\PycharmProjects\yufindProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 172, in load_label
    for obj in objects:

  File "C:\Users\Mathias\PycharmProjects\yufindProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 67, in Deserializer
    stream_or_string = stream_or_string.decode()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 460: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError, invalid continuation byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte)

Comment: no i don't see any solution, he just explain what is the error

Comment: Can you share some of the surrounding bytes `print(open('ask/dumps/ask.json', 'rb').read()[450:470])`

Comment: `manage.py` assumes that `ask.json` is encoded in `UTF-8`, which clearly isn't the case. No database query was performed. Transcode the file to `UTF-8` and everything should work.

Comment: @snakecharmerb i tried your command but it return me unvalid commutator - /dumps

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz how do i transcode file to utf-8 ? and which one, the json file ? sorry about my knowledge, i'm beginner ^^

Comment: On Unixes you can use the `iconv` utility, but on any system you just open it with a good editor (VIM, Notepad++, ...) and change the encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz okay but the encoding of which file ? the json file ?

Comment: @sorry i had bad understand your post, i'm gonna do this with ask.json thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in [Django dumpdata fails on special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64457733/django-dumpdata-fails-on-special-characters)

> To save `json` data in django the [TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) is used:
>
> > The default encoding is now `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` (...)
>
> In documentation of `locale.getpreferredencoding` fuction we can
> [read](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding):
>
> > Return the encoding used for text data, according to user preferences. User preferences are expressed differently on different
> > systems, and might not be available programmatically on some systems,
> > so this function only returns a guess.
>
> [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34345136/645146) I found "hacky" but working method to overwrite these
> settings:
>
> In file `settings.py` of your django project add these lines:
>
> ```
> import _locale
> _locale._getdefaultlocale = (lambda *args: ['en_US', 'utf8'])
> ```