# erorr manage.py dumpdata > db.json

Tags: django, django-settings

I have an error when use manage.py dumpdata > db.json

```
CommandError: Unable to serialize database: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u062f' in position 17: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django dumpdata fails on special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64457733/django-dumpdata-fails-on-special-characters)