# How to fix PostgreSQL encode

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to migrate a database from a local computer(Windows, SQLite3) to a server(Ubuntu 20, PostgreSQL).

I created a JSON dump from local SQLite3 base.

```
python manage.py dumpdata > dump.json
```

On the server, I enter into the shell and executed the commands

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
ContentType.objects.all().delete()
quit()
```

And when i'm trying to refill database

```
python manage.py loaddata dump.json
```

The console responds with this

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I would be very grateful if you could explain to me how to fix the problem.

Comment: Your JSON is probably in ANSI with BOM while Ubuntu expect it in UTF-8. Convert it to the ad-hoc encoding. As a reminder a backup is not safe until you have the guarantee that you can recover from it.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137501/django-dumpdata-utf-8-unicode) did not help?