# How do I fix the Cyrillic display?

Tags: python, sql, json, django, visual-studio-code

[my_problem_png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqX3L.png)

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, verbose_name="Название")
```

Please help me with this

I am very tormented by this problem
I'm trying to create a database fixture, but there's some kind of problem with the encoding of Russian characters, according to the guide, everything should work correctly for the YouTuber, but I have some kind of misunderstanding
python manage.py dumpdata goods.Categories > fixtures/goods/carts.json

Comment: The problem here is likely that the font in your editor doesn't contain Cyrillic glyphs.  Does your Python code display correctly?  Remember that Windows is largely brain dead about Unicode.  Was the file written in UTF-8?

Comment: None of this helped me.

Comment: Actually, the glyph shown in screenshot is the U+FFFD glyph rather than the .notdef glyph. The editor is using UTF-8 as can be seen from status bar at bottom of editor window. The json file would appear to be using a non-UTF-8 encoding legacy encoding, invalid utf-8 sequences replaced with U+FFFD.

Comment: @wicki77 first step is to identify what character encoding is being used in the database,  there would appear to be a encoding mismatch at some point in your toolchain. I suspect that a legacy encoding is being used, and the code is assuming utf-8, and using a replacement strategy on errors.

Comment: According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137501/django-dumpdata-utf-8-unicode, you should be able to say `python -Xutf8 manage.py dumpdata.goods.Categories...` to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the file encoding to one that supports Cyrillic characters, such as UTF-8.

1. Open the command palette by shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P**.
2. Search for **Change File Encoding** and select the option **Reopen with Encoding**.
3. Select **UTF-8**
4. Then reload your VSCode, this could solve this problem.

Comment: It didn't help me. I did everything as you wrote.