# Python/Django debugging: print model's containing data

Tags: python, django, debugging, printing

Maybe easy question but I don't know how to summarize it that I would find my answer.

Is it possible to print out all available fields of model?

For example in iPython I can import model and just write model name and tab will show all available fields the models have.

Is it possible to do this in code without using some sort of shell?

I would like to use some sort of command (e.a. `print_fields(self)`) and get what's inside the model.

Comment: Are you just wanted to know the field names or the data in the fields as well?

Comment: @Bryce Siedschlaw: fields is enough :) thats for help, i got my answer

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106295/django-get-list-of-model-fields

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To check fields on a model I usually use `?`:

```
>>> Person?
Type:       ModelBase
Base Class: <class 'django.db.models.base.ModelBase'>
String Form:    <class 'foo.bar.models.Person'>
Namespace:  Interactive
File:       /home/zk/ve/django/foo/bar/models.py
Docstring:
    Person(id, first_name, last_name)
```

You can also use `help()`. If you have an instance of the model you can look at `__dict__`:

```
>>> [x for x in Person().__dict__.keys() if not x.startswith('_')]
<<< ['first_name', 'last_name', 'id']
```

Comment: help() trowed all i needed :) so simple... damn i'm stupid :D oh, `?` works only in shell.

Comment: Oh good point, I misread and thought you were asking how to check in IPython!

Answer (score 25):

If you have the model instance(s) you can simply call:

```
model_queryset.all().values()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

For just the list of fields using the model class itself see [Django: Get list of model fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106295/django-get-list-of-model-fields)

or directly the documentation - for Django 1.10 there is a dedicated section on how to work with fields: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model

Comment: even a complete trace of a single object. awesome

Comment: ^^^^ this is what you are looking for if you want to see inside a queryset without a loop

Answer (score 11):

I think you just want to use `__dict__` on an instance of a model.  (It won't give methods like tab completion in ipython though).  Also using `__doc__` is quite helpful usually.

Also look into inspect http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try [something suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113096/django-dump-data-for-a-single-model/1113465#1113465):

```python
data = serializers.serialize("json", models.MyModel.objects.all(), indent=4)
```

JSON format is easy to print and read ;)

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @zeekay's answer, use the following to see the fields and corresponding values for an instance of a model:

```
[x for x in Cheese.objects.all()[0].__dict__.items() if not x[0].startswith('_')]
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you implement `__unicode__` :

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.whatever_field + self.another_field
```

Comment: because i don't know what the fields are? Thats my main problem.