# Django Deserialization Error Problem installing Fixture

Tags: python, json, django, deserialization, json-deserialization

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sparshkedia/Desktop/task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 69, in Deserializer
    yield from PythonDeserializer(objects, **options)
  File "/Users/sparshkedia/Desktop/task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 91, in Deserializer
    Model = _get_model(d["model"])
KeyError: 'model'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/sparshkedia/Desktop/task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/sparshkedia/Desktop/task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/sparshkedia/Desktop/task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/sparshkedia/Desktop/task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/sparshkedia/Desktop/task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 72, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/Users/sparshkedia/Desktop/task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 113, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/Users/sparshkedia/Desktop/task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 168, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "/Users/sparshkedia/Desktop/task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 73, in Deserializer
    raise DeserializationError() from exc
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/sparshkedia/Desktop/task/movie_rs/movies.json'
```

This is the above error showing when I am trying to deserialize my json file into the database.

My json file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "description": "A cowboy doll is profoundly threatened and jealous when a new spaceman figure supplants him as top toy in a boy's room.",
    "genre": "Animation,Adventure,Comedy,Family,Fantasy",
    "imdb_url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114709/",
    "img_url": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDU2ZWJlMjktMTRhMy00ZTA5LWEzNDgtYmNmZTEwZTViZWJkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDQ2OTk4MzI@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL__QL50.jpg",
    "movie_id": 114709,
    "title": "Toy Story",
    "users_rating": 8.3,
    "year": 1995
  },
  {
    "description": "George Banks must deal not only with the pregnancy of his daughter, but also with the unexpected pregnancy of his wife.",
    "genre": "Comedy,Family,Romance",
    "imdb_url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113041/",
    "img_url": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTEyNzg5NjYtNDU4OS00MWYxLWJhMTItYWU4NTkyNDBmM2Y0XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL__QL50.jpg",
    "movie_id": 113041,
    "title": "Father of the Bride Part II",
    "users_rating": 6,
    "year": 1995
  }]
```

What do i need to do to feed the json file into the database? 
I have also created appropriate movies model which contains all the fields as per the json file.

I am using  python manage.py loaddata movies.json for this. Is there any other approach, if yes please help me with it?

Answer (score 15):

Fixtures files must match django [serialization format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json), e.g:

```
[
    {
        "pk": "4b678b301dfd8a4e0dad910de3ae245b",
        "model": "sessions.session",
        "fields": {
            "expire_date": "2013-01-16T08:16:59.844Z",
            ...
        }
    }
]
```

So you need to rewrite your fixtures in the following way:

1. Add `model` key
2. Add `pk` field
3. Move the rest of fields to `fields` inner object

Comment: Any way i can convert my json file to the serialization format?

Comment: Either manually add required fields or write program to convert

Comment: When I called dumpdata, it had no "pk" key. I could not load the data generated in json file. I read this solution and called dumpdata again this time with "pk" by not using --natural-primary tag. I could generate json file and was able to load it successfully.

Comment: THANK YOU. This was toooo obvious to get a failure, but I did)

Answer (score 6):

I had print statements in manage.py.
That output was getting saved in fixture json file which was generating format error.
Deleting those print statements solved it.
Following is my old (bad format) fixtures .json file. I deleted first line and it worked.

```
app.yaml file = dev_app.yaml
[
  {
    "model": "plans.planslevel1",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "name": "abc",
      "description": "xyz"
    }
  
  }]
```

Answer (score 3):

> Sometimes objects are not closed properly

- open the JSON file, Have a look at the errors which is highlighted by pycharmIDE.
- if any objects are not closed, fix it manually.

Answer (score 1):

One other possibility is that if you ever put a print statement in your settings.py it may end up in your fixtures if you are using dumpdata.

Answer (score 0):

In django 4.1 you can use ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/initial-data/)):

```py
python manage.py loaddata ./fixtures/YOUR_DATA.json
```

and fixtures structure must be like this for example:

```
[
    {
        "model": "movie.movie",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "description": "A cowboy doll is profoundly threatened and jealous when a new spaceman figure supplants him as top toy in a boy's room.",
            "genre": "Animation,Adventure,Comedy,Family,Fantasy",
            "imdb_url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114709/",
            "img_url": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDU2ZWJlMjktMTRhMy00ZTA5LWEzNDgtYmNmZTEwZTViZWJkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDQ2OTk4MzI@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL__QL50.jpg",
            "movie_id": 114709,
            "title": "Toy Story",
            "users_rating": 8.3,
            "year": 1995
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing the json file format to UTF-8 helped.