# How to backup PostgreSQL database using Django?

Tags: django

> I'm trying to export Postgresql database but it returns backup() takes no arguments (1 given). I
>   tried various methods, but unable to export database.

```
from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen
​
​
def backup():
    version = 11
    # postgresDir = "D:/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin"
    postgresDir = str("D:/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/").split('\\')[-1:][0]
​
    directory = postgresDir
    filename = 'myBackUp2'  # output filename here
    saveDir = Path("D:/{}.tar".format(filename))  # output directory here
    file = PureWindowsPath(saveDir)
​
    host = 'localhost'
    user = 'postgres'
    port = '5432'
    dbname = 'BPS_Server'  # database name here
    proc = Popen(['pg_dump', '-h', host, '-U', user, '-W', '-p', port,
                   '-F', 't', '-f', str(file), '-d', dbname],
                    cwd=directory, shell=True, stdin=PIPE)
    proc.wait()
​
backup()
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using Django? This looks like a regular python script to me, can you try moving the script out of your Django project and executing it? Also maybe rename the backup function, just a wild guess

Comment: I tried to run the file out of my django project  but it's not working. It returns FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for backup from postgresql you have two ways:

1) use a bash script and run it every day or month for get backup :
   you can get more information [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Linux)

2) use `fixture` in django:

```
def backup():
    filename = 'myBackUp2'  # output filename here
    saveDir = open("D:/{}.json".format(filename), 'w')

    # change application_name with your django app which you want to get backup from it
    call_command('dumpdata', 'application_name', stdout=saveDir, indent=3)
    saveDir.close()
```

`call_command()` uses for execute django command and `dumpdata` uses for get fixture from a table. 
[more information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata)

Comment: I create db.json file. Sorry , i'm confused what shall i put in dumpdata and application_name. Shall I put path to db.json file in open("D:/{}.json".format(filename), 'w') ?

Comment: `dumpdata` generate a json file which contains your data. you know, in django we can define some applications in `INSTALLED_APPS` so for get dumpdata you should define an application which you define in `INSTALLED_APPS` and django generate its dumpdata

Comment: see this  [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113096/django-dump-data-for-a-single-model)

Comment: I want to get backup of whole database.  I did python manage.py dumpdata. I can see the dumpdata created in python shell but I don't have any idea  where it is created.

Comment: I tried it by using subprocess also.It creates gzip file but empty file.

Comment: do that with `django-background-task` or `redis-queue` for sample you can execute this command `python manage.py dumpdata your-application` but before execute this command be sure your database has data.

Comment: you can use `call_command()` in your code and generate a dumpdata

Comment: let me write a example and share with you in gitlab

Comment: I'm stuck in another problem also. My project is runs in browser but when i tried to import anythin in python shell, it returns 'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: check [this repo](https://gitlab.com/khashayarghamati/dumpdata_sample) and be in touch with me via my email address ;)

Comment: I have sent you request in hangout.

Comment: I haven't new request please send me a mail